# How to draw two lines in HighStocks using candlestick with intraday

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to draw two lines in HighStocks using JavaScript with their example [candlestick with intraday code](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/intraday-candlestick/). For some reason I can't get it to work

I am trying to just generate two extra lines at the end of my candlestick data, here is what i have (testing with just one line but it wont work). You can see the line im trying to put in is called test

```js
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=new-intraday.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            title: {
                text: 'AAPL stock price by minute'
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'hour',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1h'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1D'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    count: 1,
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                selected: 1,
                inputEnabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL',
                type: 'candlestick',
                data: data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
            
            series: [{
              name: 'test',
                type: 'line',
                data: [200.0, 201.0, 300.0, 400.0],
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not add two series arrays in your chart options object. You should use one series array and inside this array add new series object:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    type: 'candlestick',
    data: data,
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    }
  }, {
    name: 'test',
    type: 'line',
    data: [200.0, 201.0, 300.0, 400.0],
  }]
```

The problem with this case is that you didn't give any x values to your line points, so it will start from 1970 year right now.

You need to add x values so line will start just where you want.

Here you can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uj0kzL4c/